# Why is the lightbox jQuery plugin not working for me?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Going by the instructions both here: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ and in the book "Murach's JavaScript and jQuery" (on pages 320 and 321), I'm trying to add lightbox functionality to my site.

I added lightbox.css (and screen.css, thtinking that might also be required) to my Content folder, and both lightbox.js and jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js (because it was included in the lightbox download, and I figured lightbox needed it) to my Scripts folder.

I also added to my Images folder the following images included in the lightbox download: close.png, loading.gif, next.png, and prev.png.

I've got this html and jQuery code (this is the entire Default.cshtml at this point):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "el Garrapata - Spoon!!!";
}

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Spring</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Summer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Fall</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Winter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <a href="Images/Fullsize/Landscapes/Spring_2013 04 06_2293.jpg" rel="lightbox" ><img src="Images/Thumbnails/Landscapes/Spring_2013 04 06_2293_th.jpg" width="300" height="200"></a>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
    </div>

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
        });
    </script>
```

...but it doesn't work: although that one thumbnail image displays in the "Spring" tab, clicking it simply causes the screen to go mostly dark - it becomes "grayed out" to the point of almost opaqueness.

The lightbox download also includes jquery-1.7.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js

I'm referencing newer versions in _SiteLayout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
```

Could this be the problem? Am I "stuck" using older versions of jQuery and jQueryUI if I want to use lightbox?

BTW, I tried to post this at lightbox's internal forum, but was unable to log in, neither with Fakebook or Google (although I have (reluctantly in the case of the former) accounts with both; also the OpenID jazz I tried, but it seems to expect an URL...???)

### UPDATE

Note: I am going to bountify this question for 100 points ASAP. If I get an answer prior to that, I will award the bounty post-answer.

### UPDATE 2

I've switched to fancyBox, but the large (href) image still hugs the left side of the page when clicking on the "thumbnail", not the center. Here's all the Razor, HTML, and jQuery (some of the image code elided for brevity):

selected from _SiteLayout.cshtml:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- May want to replace the above before deploying with use of a CDN:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
OR: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
..and similar for jquery-ui -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
```

from Default.cshtml:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Garrapata";
}

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Spring</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Summer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Fall</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Winter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Fullsize/Landscapes/Spring_2013 04 06_2293.jpg"><img src="Images/Thumbnails/Landscapes/Spring_2013 04 06_2293_th.jpg" width="294" height="196" alt="" /></a>
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="Images/Fullsize/Landscapes/Spring_2013 04 06_2295.jpg"><img src="Images/Thumbnails/Landscapes/Spring_2013 04 06_2295_th.jpg" width="294" height="196" alt="" /></a>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
    </div>

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect : 'elastic'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Also, I don't see the "Close" button in the NE corner - perhaps because the large image, taking up all the "top" space, has not left room for it to be visible.

### UPDATE 3

Now I see that the .css and .js files I was referencing in _SiteLayout.cshtml are supposed to be in /fancybox/source

It seems like instead of what I have now, namely:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
```

...what *should* work would be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
```

...as I have copied those files into those locations.

Does it *really* have to be that particular (and, it seems to me, rather peculiar) way you mentioned?

Since it would seem based on what I've got that the css and js would not be found at all, I'm surprised it even works as well as it does...

Comment: Why don't you try Fancybox instead of Lightbox. It' an alternative to Lightbox and very easy to use. http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Fancybox seems not to have been updated in 2.5 years (http://fancybox.net/changelog/); this makes me nervous.

Comment: I got two questions 1. Did you create the folder structure `/fancybox/source/`? 2. Did you download fancybox2 from the site?

Comment: Answers: 1) No 2) Yes.
Where exactly is "/fancybox/source" supposed to be, in relation to everything else? I have jquery.fancybox.css in my "Content" folder, jquery.fancybox.js in my Scripts folder, and the images (fancybox*.gif and fancybox*.gif, as well as "close.png" etc, in my Images folder.

Comment: Do this. Just get the `source` folder in the `Fancybox folder` which you downloaded. Rename the `source` folder to `fancybox`. Then link the css file and the js file in the `fancybox` folder correctly.

Comment: My answer is too long, so I've updated my original post again (Update 3)

Comment: I have update my answer, please check update #1.

Comment: Okay, I will work on that when I get home - thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lightbox you're trying to implement only works with jQuery **jquery-1.7.2** or below and also you don't need `jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js` in order for the Lightbox to work.

For this version of lightbox to work, you need `lightbox.css`, `jquery-1.7.2.js`  and `lightbox.js`.

Shown below is a sample code similar to your one where the Lightbox is working. ( Paste this code on a Text editor, save it as a HTML page and open it using your Web Browser )

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- 
         **** Things you need to do****
         1. SPECIFY LIGHTBOX CSS FILE
         2. SPECIFY JQUERY JS (jquery-1.7.2) FILE
         3. SPECIFY LIGHTBOX JS FILE 
    -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Spring</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Summer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Fall</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Winter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <a href="http://pages.swcp.com/~jamii/OtherCats/coco.jpg" rel="lightbox" >
            <img src="http://pages.swcp.com/~jamii/OtherCats/coco.jpg" width="300" height="200">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use fancybox instead of lightbox, which works with the latest jQuery versions. The latest version of Fancybox is **[Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)**, You can download it from this Site - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

**Code for implementing Fancybox 2**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Add jquery library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".fancybox").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'elastic',
                closeEffect : 'elastic'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Spring</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Summer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Fall</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Winter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <a class="fancybox" href="http://pages.swcp.com/~jamii/OtherCats/coco.jpg" rel="lightbox" > <!--Add class "fancybox"-->
            <img src="http://pages.swcp.com/~jamii/OtherCats/coco.jpg" width="300" height="200">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE #1**

You need all the files in the source folder to implement fancybox (helpers folder is optional). You need to keep the fancybox css, js and images in one location. What you can do is copy the `source` folder into your web app directory and rename it to `fancybox`. Then you can call the css file, js files from your html page. 
eg:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Cool; that code worked okay in IE, and just fine in Chrome and Firefox. One of them, though, caused all kinds of weird things to happen in my browser: other tabs were opened willy-nilly, the Stack Overflow page switched from this one to one I had never visited before, etc. Bizarre! Anyway, it sounds like FancyBox2 might be in my (near) future. I don't like the idea of falling back to version 1.7.2 when version 2.0.0 just came out - what is this, the remote wilderness of northern Canada?!? Also, that kitty made me want to get another feline.

Comment: As mentioned on the [jQuery Site](http://jquery.com/download/) "jQuery 2.0 has the same API as jQuery 1.9, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8" therefore it's better if you can use jQuery 1.9. I have some experience on web development and we always use fancybox instead of lightbox because it supports almost all the browsers and latest versions of jQuery. This is why i told you to use fancybox any its you who need to decide :)

Comment: Fancybox works, so I'll give you the 100 point bounty bonus ASAP. The large image displays all to the left of the screen, instead of centered like I would like it to be, but I'm sure that won't be a huge roadblock/obstacle.

Comment: It is great if you can show me your code. You can use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) to upload the code and share.

Comment: @ClayShannon You need to first call the `jquery.fancybox.css` and then `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` inside the <head></head> tags. Here is a example for you - jsfiddle.net/UNjZE. The Image is centered and i can't see any problem in that. I have also updated my answer.

Comment: I'll try it tonight and let you know - I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: BTW, I think I do need the jqueryui - but for the tabs, not the *box.

Comment: I think the only difference between your code and mine* (in the fancyBox example) is the "elastic" bits. Also, I don't recollect seeing the "Close" button in the NE corner - maybe I failed to add that image, or am not referencing it, or have it in the wrong spot.
* Also, I have "$(".tabs").tabs" or similar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28753/discussion-between-frozenhaart-and-clay-shannon)

Comment: I've updated my post with my code. The large images still "float left" rather than centering.

Comment: Your Update #1 works like a champ; you sure earned your 100 points, frostyheart, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes It is not also working, when you have other .js libraries included before lightbox. Put it just after jquery.

Comment: Thats Right . Thank You .