# Simple lightbox example, not running...why?

Tags: lightbox2

i found this lightbox example on stackoverflow: 
[Why is the lightbox jQuery plugin not working for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138766/why-is-the-lightbox-jquery-plugin-not-working-for-me/31895893#31895893)

i did ask a question there but it was deleted and i was told to use the "ask a question button" so here i am

this code does not run:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- 
         **** Things you need to do****
         1. SPECIFY LIGHTBOX CSS FILE
         2. SPECIFY JQUERY JS (jquery-1.7.2) FILE
         3. SPECIFY LIGHTBOX JS FILE 
    -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
    <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/js/lightbox.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Spring</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Summer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Fall</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">Winter</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <a href="https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2015/229th-anniversary-of-the-first-ascent-of-mont-blanc-5711572991213568.2-hp.jpg" rel="lightbox" >
            <img src="https://www.google.de/logos/doodles/2015/229th-anniversary-of-the-first-ascent-of-mont-blanc-5711572991213568.2-hp.jpg" width="300" height="200">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

all the "versions" are specified...how can it not work? i just get a small picture and if i click on it it behaves like a normal link.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied this verbatim, the error is the fact that the jQuery script included in that sample no longer exist. You can notice this easily in your browser's developer console. So you have to find the required jQuery version from some other place.

I would recommend using some other scripts that are usable with more current jQuery version though, otherwise you'll be forced to use an ancient one.

Comment: thank you, ive contacted the author or lightbox2 which is indeed the owner of lokeshdhakar.com to reupload it

Answer (score -2):

Include your scripts before `</body>` tag. Then lightbox will be work correctly.

Comment: scripts can be added in <body> also