# Image gallery won't load (lightbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, lightbox

I'm a beginner trying to implement a Lightbox image gallery in my rails site. I donwloaded and followed the guidelines in the Lightbox [site](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/), as well as other ideas that I found on YouTube. The images appear as expected in rows, but upon clicking the images simply open in the same tab (i.e. not in a full-screen navigation, using the lightbox functionality). I have tried to make sense of an analogous problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138766/why-is-the-lightbox-jquery-plugin-not-working-for-me), but I'm not understanding how the use of jquery there pertains to the situation at hand.

In the console I'm seeing the following error, though I'm not sure how to use this to to fix the problem: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/lightbox-plus-jquery.js")`

My application.html.erb looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <% if controller.controller_name == 'spanish_pages' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/spanish_header' %>
  <% elsif controller.controller_name == 'english_pages' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/english_header' %>
  <% end %> 

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The page intended for the gallery is:

```
<% provide(:title, "Imágenes") %>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Imágenes</h1>
  <div class="gallery">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="pp1.jpg" data-title="my first caption" data-lightbox="pp">
          <img src="pp1.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="pp2.jpg" data-title="my second caption" data-lightbox="pp">
          <img src="pp2.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div><div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="pp4.jpg" data-title="my third caption" data-lightbox="pp">
          <img src="pp4.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div><div class="col-lg-3">
        <a href="pp5.jpg" data-title="my fourth caption" data-lightbox="pp">
          <img src="pp5.jpg" width="200px" class="img-thumbnail">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div> <!---row1 ends -->
  </div>
</div>

<script src="assets/javascripts/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
```

I have also added lightbox-plus-jquery.js to assets/javascripts/, and added lightbox.css (renamed to lightbox.css.scss) to assets/stylesheets. Any help will be much appreciated!